# Electromagnetic Tensor - Magnetic Elements

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, tensor-calculus

Given the electromagnetic stress tensor $F^{\mu\nu}$ such that $F^{ij}=\epsilon_{ijk}B_k$, I attempted to write the 'inverse' and got the following.

$$B_i=\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{ijk}F^{jk}$$

This works the way I want it to. That is to say, it returns $B_1=F^{23}$ etc. just as the other form produces. Here's where I'm unsure if what I've done was 'correct.' If I try back substitution I assume I should find $B_i=B_i$. However,

\begin{align}
B_i&=\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{ijk}F^{jk} \\
&=\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{jkm}B_m \\
&=\frac{1}{2}(\delta_{im}\delta_{jj}-\delta_{mj}\delta_{ij})B_m \\
&=0
\end{align}

Did I define $B$ incorrectly, or am I not allowed to back-sub the way I've done for deeper mathematical reasons?

Answer (score 0):

You contracted the epsilon symbols the wrong way, so the indices are off in the third line.
\begin{align}
B_i &= \frac{1}{2} \epsilon _{ijk} F^{jk} \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \epsilon _{ijk} \epsilon ^{jkl} B_{l} \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \epsilon _{ijk} \epsilon ^{ljk} B_{l} \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \epsilon _{ijk} \epsilon ^{ljk} B_{l} \\
&= \frac{1}{2} (2 \delta _i ^l) B_l \\ 
&= B_i
\end{align}

Comment: I think I understand now. I should have defined $F^{ij}$ with superscripts not subscripts. On this note, how does $\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{mjk}$ compare to $\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon^{mjk}$ from an operation, or matrix point of view? Is one supposed to be a an inner product and the other an outer product?

Comment: F is usually called the field tensor. The term stress tensor is reserved for an object containing energy, momentum, energy transport and stress.

Comment: Well, since you are only concerned with the spatial part of $F$ and since (incidentally) there is no difference between upper and lower indices in Euclidean 3-space, in this case the difference between $\epsilon _{ijk} \epsilon _{mjk}$ and $\epsilon _{ijk} \epsilon ^{ijk} $ happens to be rather typographical. However, correct index placement usually makes formulae easier to read. On a general manifold for some tensor $A$, $A_{ijk} A _{lmn}$ would be a tensor product, but then contracting indices without first raising or lowering them does not make sense.